# Laravel Syntax Error acessing parent folder

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a school project and I am following a video from codecourse and he uses laravel-adjacency-list, I installed it and when I try to write it in the same way he does I get this :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'recursive `laravel_cte` as ((select *, 0 as `depth`, cast(`id` as char(65535)) a' at line 1 (SQL: with recursive `laravel_cte` as ((select *, 0 as `depth`, cast(`id` as char(65535)) as `path` from `objects` where `objects`.`id` = 9) union all (select `objects`.*, `depth` - 1 as `depth`, concat(`path`, ., `objects`.`id`) from `objects` inner join `laravel_cte` on `laravel_cte`.`parent_id` = `objects`.`id`)) select * from `laravel_cte`)
```

Github:

```
ancestorsAndSelf(): The model's recursive parents and itself.
```

My code :

[image]

His code :

[image]

Comment: Never add Images of the code, add code snippet instead.

Comment: Are you working with the MySql Server version or Maria DB?

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
in the video he has  DB_CONNECTION=pgsql is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't always have to blame the code.

The error is because your MySQL version doesn't have a recursive CTE feature. You need to upgrade MySQL version to 8.0 or later.

Common table expression or CTE only available in MySQL version 8.0 or later. You should have the right version of MySQL installed.

#### Compatibility :

- MySQL `8.0+`
- MariaDB `10.2+`
- PostgreSQL `9.4+`
- SQLite `3.8.3+`
- SQL Server `2008+`

Comment: My current version is : mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Win64 (x86_64)

Comment: It shows 5.7.24 how do i update it from here?

Comment: Just uninstall your current version, then installing compatible version as I mentioned above